# Using Awk Commands in R to Extract Data

Tags: r

This question is a continuation and clarification of this question, [Extracting Data from Text Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261776/extracting-data-from-text-files) I shut this question down but I'm still having difficulty applying the answers to my problem.

I'm sat at a Windows machine and I'm using Putty to submit jobs to a supercomputer.  The jobs return files of the following format, http://www.d.umn.edu/~psiders/courses/chem4642/quantumchemsoftware/tutorial/gamess/methanol.out.  (Note that this is a .log file rather than a .out file which is important for reading what follows).

I interrogate the files using the following shell commands,

```
grep MAXIMUM FileName.log | awk '{print $4}'
```

which returns a series of numbers that I copy to my clipboard and then run the following R file,

```
MAX1 <- readClipboard(format=1, raw=FALSE) # reading data
plot(MAX1, type="b", ylim=c(0,0.00005), xlim=c(0,50), 
main=bquote(After~ .(length(MAX1))~ iterations))
abline(h=0.00001, col="red")
```

which returns a graphical representation of the calculation.

(Other people do this with perl scripts).

When the calculation is complete I extract the file from the supercomputer and store it on my windows system.

What I want to do is to prepare an R script that can interrogate the .log file within a windows environment.

I know how to change the directory, list the files and use readLines to get the file into R,

```
grep("MAXIMUM",readLines("FileName.log"), value=TRUE) #searching files
```

but this doesn't return the values as a string of numbers that I can put into plot.  It looks like character strings without 'awk' being applied to them.

Can anyone help me iron out this last bit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `g` is the result of the `grep` then:

```
read.table(text = g)[, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with grep and an approach similar to awk this could help:

```
selected.lines <- grep("MAXIMUM",readLines("FileName.log"), value=TRUE)
values <- unlist(lapply(selected.lines, function(x) { s<-strsplit(x, " +"); return(s[[1]][5]) }))
```

But rethinking the approach with read.table could be more straightforward and fast.

Comment: The read.table answer was the best; but you knew that ... problem is, I didn't.  Thanks for your help, @vodka.

Comment: I was not aware of the text option and didn't have the time to read the help. So bad me :)